# how to read only the weight instead of the whole text from the serial port

Tags: c#, asp.net, serial-port

I have a Barcode Weighing machine Sartorious BSA  4235 and it is connected to a serial port(COM). I am trying to display it in a text box in my winforms asp.net application. The data received is coming in the format N     +    5.249 g . I need to get only the weight value. But when I am trying to extract only the weight, as the fluctuation of the weight is happening, and as I am replacing the string with decimal the value, the textbox is overwriting instead of only the last digit fluctuation similar to weighing scale. So the user is unable to finalize the weight. The fluctuation is happening at a faster rate. Here are the settings for the serial port:
Baud Rate:1200
Parity:None
Data Bits:7
Stop Bits:1
and Here is the code:

```
 _serialPort = new SerialPort(PortName, BaudRate, (Parity)Enum.ToObject(typeof(Parity), paritybits), databits, (StopBits)Enum.ToObject(typeof(StopBits), stopbits));  


private void SerialPortOnDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs serialDataReceivedEventArgs)
    {
        if (IsFire)
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)     //<-- Makes sure the function is invoked to work properly in the UI-Thread
                BeginInvoke(new Closure(() => { SerialPortOnDataReceived(sender, serialDataReceivedEventArgs); }));     //<-- Function invokes itself
            else
            {
                int dataLength = _serialPort.BytesToRead;
                byte[] data = new byte[dataLength];
                int nbrDataRead = _serialPort.Read(data, 0, dataLength);
                if (nbrDataRead == 0)
                    return;
                string str = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);

                double number;

                if (Double.TryParse(str, out number))
                {
                    txtBCGGrassWeight.Text = string.Format("{0:0.000}", str);
                }
                else
                {
                    var doubleArray = Regex.Split(str, @"[^0-9\.]+")
                    .Where(c => c != "." && c.Trim() != "");

                    string[] str1 = ((System.Collections.IEnumerable)doubleArray)
                  .Cast<object>()
                  .Select(x => x.ToString())
                  .ToArray();
                    if (str1 != null && str1.Length > 0)
                    {
                        txtBCGGrassWeight.Text = string.Format("{0:0.000}", str1[0]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean exactly by "So the user is unable to finalize the weight. " ? you are getting noisy values did I understand you correctly?

Comment: In the weighing machine the weight is becoming stable and only the last digits are fluctuating. But in my text-box the weight is overwriting every time. When the machine becomes stable after that also ondatareceive is firing again and again. I am not getting noisy values but like this N + 5.249 g

Comment: Is the last digit significant? Could you "ignore" it? Or at least smoothen its signal? For example by averaging over the last 10 readings?

Comment: No, I want three decimal points. Is there any way to display just like the machine does?

Comment: `ondatareceive` will fire as long as the machine is sending data. "weight is becoming stable and only the last digits are fluctuating. But in my text-box the weight is overwriting every time" I don't understand why the overwriting is a problem, doesn't the weight come from the machine? can you post an example of the problematic output and of the desired output?

Comment: "No, I want three decimal points" - Well, I guess the machine isn't giving you the accuracy to actually use 3 decimals ... which btw would be milligrams. What are you weighing?

Comment: @Fildor Sartorious is building precision scales :)

Comment: I am weighing Gold. Machine is returning accurately three decimals and the last digit fluctuates for some time and becomes stable.

Comment: @MongZhu Ah, didn't know that, thanks. So if the device _should_ be able to deliver stable mg readings, then my bet is on a mechanical problem. "the last digit fluctuates for some time and becomes stable." - then why is that a Problem? That's totally expected. Any measurement device will have to "swing into stability".

Comment: still your weight is overwritten with the new values that the machine is sending. Where is the problem if the value becomes stable after a certain time?

Comment: Ah, now we are getting closer ... so I guess your EventQueue isn't able to keep up with the update rate from the machine. I'd try to not marshal all the Eventhandler code to the UI but only the part where the Text value is set. For starters.

Comment: Also, I have doubts about the correctness of your `else` block from the `if (Double.TryParse ... `

Comment: Sorry but I did not get that ('d try to not marshal all the Eventhandler code)

Comment: it means basically that you have old values still hanging in there and you don't get the recent realistic value. The timer would make it as fast as you want

Comment: In the beginning you do a `if (InvokeRequired)` and if so you marshal the complete reading from Serial to the UI Thread. You should not do that. Marshal only the part where you actually modify UI Controls.

Comment: I have doubts about the correctness of your else block- I am checking whether the string has only double values or is it having strings just like N+g.

Comment: That part is ok. If it is not able to diretcly parse, you'll have to clean it up. But I would make a Regex match for a number instead of what you are doing. By the way "[^" = "Not" in regex.

Comment: For example use a [Regex match](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/twcw2f1c(v=vs.110).aspx) for `\d+\.\d+`

Comment: "Marshal the complete reading" - by doing `BeginInvoke(new Closure(() => { SerialPortOnDataReceived(sender, serialDataReceivedEventArgs); }));` You shift the code including `_serialPort.Read` onto the UI thread. So you are doing I/O on the UI thread which is not good. You should get your reading as a string an only then BeginInvoke only the line `txtBCGGrassWeight.Text = ... `

Comment: Also see the example for regex match with string and pattern here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z2heewz(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3):

This is untested and may need some syntactical correction, but try it:

```
private void SerialPortOnDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs serialDataReceivedEventArgs)
{
    if (IsFire)
    {
        int dataLength = _serialPort.BytesToRead;
        byte[] data = new byte[dataLength];
        int nbrDataRead = _serialPort.Read(data, 0, dataLength);
        if (nbrDataRead == 0) return;
        string str = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);

        double number;
        bool success = false;
        if (Double.TryParse(str, out number))
        {
            success = true;
        }
        else
        {
            var match = Regex.Match( str, @"\d+\.\d+");
            if( match.Success )
            {
                success = Double.TryParse(match.Value, out number);
            }
        }

        if( success )
        {
            SetText(number.ToString());
        }
    }
}

delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);

private void SetText(string text)
{
    // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
    // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
    // If these threads are different, it returns true.
    if (this.txtBCGGrassWeight.InvokeRequired)
    {
        SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
        this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
    }
    else
    {
        this.txtBCGGrassWeight.Text = string.Format("{0:0.000}",text);

    }
}
```